# I can not load null_space method in python 3.5

Tags: python, scipy

According to documentation, there should be a `null_space` function in the `scipy.linalg` package. I am using python3, but I can not import the function:

```
import scipy.linalg.null_space as null
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-142-eb3cbfa6f87d>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.linalg.null_space as null

ImportError: No module named 'scipy.linalg.null_space'
```

Is this not strange? What is wrong here? I also can import scipy itself just fine.

Comment: Try `from scipy.linalg import null_space as null`

Comment: from scipy.linalg import null_space as null
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-143-7f225d7c2d82>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import null_space as null

ImportError: cannot import name 'null_space'

Comment: What about `import scipy.linalg as la; la.null_space`?

Comment: la.null_space(C)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-148-644dcd6bc64f>", line 1, in <module>
    la.null_space(C)

AttributeError: module 'scipy.linalg' has no attribute 'null_space'

Comment: Well, at least it's consistent

Comment: Yes, it survived restart of the IDE, so persistent and consistent . :D

Comment: What's `scipy.__version__`?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here. The first is that [`null_space`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html) wasn't added to scipy until version 1.1.0. The [release notes](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/doc/release/1.1.0-notes.rst#scipy-linalg-improvements) mention this explicitly.

You have two workarounds available in this regard. The simplest in the long run is to simply upgrade scipy. The other is to copy the function out of [`scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py`:333](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c3fd6d11aa1476f8d284c205fcf585c20a9f9ac5/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py#L333) on GitHub, stick it in your utilities somewhere, and use that.

The second issue is your import syntax. An [import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) of the form `import x as y` only works when `x` is a module. To import a module attribute, you need to use `from x import a [as b]` notation:

```
from scipy.linalg import null_space
null_space(...)
```

Alternatively, you can use `import x [as y]` notation, to access the attribute through the module:

```
import scipy.linalg.null_space
scipy.linalg.null_space(...)
```

Or

```
import scipy.linalg as la
la.null_space(...)
```

The error message pretty much tells you exactly what the problem is, but it's a little cryptic if you don't already know what to look for.

Comment: May be my python system is messed up, but the error is still there:  from scipy.linalg import null_space
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-144-6d517f6bd28d>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import null_space

ImportError: cannot import name 'null_space'